# android post request (no value for the post[argument])

Tags: php, android, post, get

I could not make a post request from my android app, there must be some stupid error that I could see it...

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.smth.net/some.php");
try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pa", "555"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pb", "550"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
} catch (Exception e) { 
//no error thrown
}
```

When I go to the browser and do a request to
http://www.smth.net/some.php?ga=15523&ga=34515
only the Get values are inserted which is okey.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO t1 (a,b) VALUES (" . $_GET["ga"] . "," . $_GET["gb"] . ")");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO t1 (a,b) VALUES (" . $_POST["pa"] . "," . $_POST["pb"] . ")");
```

Comment: Why don't you see what the exception is? That's exactly what they are there for...

Comment: Try to `var_dump` values and get its result in debug - check what is posted with `HttpPost`.

Comment: there is no exception I print Log.v(tag,"does not enter in the cathc");, so it never throws an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know what happen,

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.smth.net/some.php");
    httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.smth.net/some.php");

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pa", "555"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pb", "550"));

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

And check response, What you get..

Comment: Log.v("vvv",response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()); it returns 200, but nothing is inserted

Comment: 200 means, success execution, just check server side your php script how it handle data..

Comment: OK 200

The request was fulfilled.

Comment: yes I know but the $_POST["pa"] has a value "" -> empty, it is something wrong in my request

Comment: I am sure that  $_POST["pa"]  is empty I checked many times, but I could not understand why it is send as empty :(

Comment: Can you just print the value at server side which are you getting from request?